# How can I adjust my Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM)? (If it's wrong)

Tags: python, model, gaussian, normal-distribution

I have 1 dimensional data of clinical analysis such as leukocytes in blood. Regardless of the type of analysis they look more or less this way.
[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo2ae.png)
Our guess (which is more than a guess) is that data is a bimodal of gaussians, one for the really sick patients and another one for the rest. In this case we can see one in the middle and the other one at bottom right.

I've been playing with GMM

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2, random_state=42)
gmm.fit(data['obs_value_nm'].values.reshape(-1,1))
data['target_class'] = gmm.predict(data['obs_value_nm'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

And I get this classification of the data:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(18, 6))
sns.kdeplot(data=datos.obs_value_nm, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('Before GMM', fontsize=16)
sns.kdeplot(data=datos[datos.target_class==0].obs_value_nm, label='Component 1', ax=ax[1])
sns.kdeplot(data=datos[datos.target_class==1].obs_value_nm, label='Component 2', ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('After GMM', fontsize=16)
```

[GMM distribution classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrcHI.png)
Which, at least for me, doesn't really look accurate.

Even more, I have plotted both distributions with the mean and std over the histograms with scipy.stats:

```
x = np.linspace(group['Min'].values[0], group['Max'].values[0], 400)
y = norm.pdf(x, loc = stat['media'].values[0], scale = stat['std'].values[0])
```

[Histogram + GMM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taSPi.png)

My main purpose is to get the means and standard deviations of both gaussians. Because I want to identify the possible outliers of the data with the distance to the mean compared to the deviation. And I would like to be able to plot both distributions over the histogram with some good results...
I'm kinda lost at this point, since I'm not finding to much documentation.
Sorry If my English it isn't the proper one, but I tried my best!